# Android bitmap decodingA

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to decode a bitmap with pixel size 1024*683 with the api
decodefile(filepath) but process runs out of memory while decoding the
image.

I need the bitmap object for this image at one go without any scaling
as i have to work with NDK reading the pixel values using this bitmap.
Therefore any scaling or sampling method can't be applied in my case.

I wonder how come  this is possible that just decoding a file with
such size would need any in-around method. There is enough heap size
available for this process.

Your opinion and perspective in this matter will be appreciated.

Thanks
Nawab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem when I had memory leaks in one of my activities. There were not only view leaks, but bitmap leaks too. And memory consumed by bitmaps is not taken into account when DDMS shows free heap space.

Comment: For the time being i have solved this issue by increasing the heap size for the application in the virtual device to 16MB. I am not sure if its a optimum size of the heap for a single application. But by doing this i am able to solve this problem.

Comment: It's not a good idea really because some devices still have 16MB heap space.

Comment: Yeah you are right...but the point is that my application is not suitable for such phones having very low heap memory. But still I will look for some method to avoid the utilisation of the heap to such extent at the given moment for decoding the bitmap of such size.

Comment: That's not a big bitmap. My app works with bitmaps of the same size and it never crashes with OOM. I recommend you to use Memory Analyzer for Eclipse. It's a great tool that can help you find memory leaks and memory consumption overheads in your app.